# How do I install taosBenchmark when building TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I have a MacOS computer with the M1 chip and I am running a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04.2 with ARM64. I built TDengine following the documentation on the GitHub page at https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine but when I tried to run the demo using taosBenchmark, the taosTools were not built with TDengine. How do I build taosBenchmark with TDengine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for arm environment, you can try following steps

```
cd TDengine
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir debug
cd debug
cmake .. -DCPUTYPE=aarch64/aarch32 -DBUILD_TOOLS=true
cmake --build .
```